# Parsing JSON to YAML fails when using $ and {

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, yaml

I am trying to convert JSON to YAML using js-yaml but I cannot seem to get my set parsed correctly.
Consider following code:

```js
function callBackFunc(require,module,exports) {
const yaml = require('js-yaml')

const content = {
  stages: {
    jobs: [{
        scripts: [
          '/opt/scripts/git/git-repository-information-restore.sh',
          'cp ${bamboo.gitconfig_path} ${bamboo.build.working.directory}',
          'cp ${bamboo.npmrc_path} ${bamboo.build.working.directory}',
          'cp ${bamboo.gitcredentials_path} ${bamboo.build.working.directory}',
          'docker build --build-arg VERSION=patch --build-arg REPO=${bamboo.planRepository.repositoryUrl} --no-cache .',
          '/opt/scripts/docker/stop-docker-containers.sh'
        ]
      },
      {
        requirements: 'REMOTE_ONLY'
      }
    ]
  }
}
console.log(yaml.safeDump(content))
}

$.getScript( "https://pastebin.com/raw/PcCb27LS", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It returns:

```
stages:
  jobs:
    - scripts:
        - /opt/scripts/git/git-repository-information-restore.sh
        - 'cp ${bamboo.gitconfig_path} ${bamboo.build.working.directory}'
        - 'cp ${bamboo.npmrc_path} ${bamboo.build.working.directory}'
        - 'cp ${bamboo.gitcredentials_path} ${bamboo.build.working.directory}'
        - >-
      docker build --build-arg VERSION=patch --build-arg
      REPO=${bamboo.planRepository.repositoryUrl} --no-cache .
        - /opt/scripts/docker/stop-docker-containers.sh
    - requirements: REMOTE_ONLY
```

For some reason unknown to me, the scripts nodes are surrounded with `'` and `>-` gets inserted.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but the fix Terry proposed did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two issues here:

- A newline fold (>) being inserted in the docker build line.
- The script nodes being quoted (')

The first is easy enough to fix, we can tell js-yaml to increase the max line width like so:

```
const options = { lineWidth: 1000 };
console.log(yaml.safeDump(content, options));
```

The second is more difficult, the reason js-yaml is quoting the script lines is that they contain curly brace characters, which must be quoted in Yaml. The output will still be valid, so perhaps once it is clear why the strings are quoted there is no real issue!

Comment: The problem of the newline fold is indeed fixed by setting the width. I do not understand what you mean with 'so perhaps once it is clear why the strings are quoted, there is no real issue'. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Oh sure, yes. Js-yaml is quoting the script strings because if a string contains a special character, (e.g. :, {, }, [, ], ,, &, *, # .. ) the string must be quoted in Yaml. The library is doing the right thing, and the yaml that is output is valid and correct. The first line is not quoted since it contains no special characters.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. So I can assume that the output is valid now. So lets hope when I import it in Bamboo, it will adhere to the YAML specs.

Answer (score 1):

They are different ways of quoting strings in YAML. Those lines are being quoted because curly brackets have special meaning in YAML. (The `>` signals quoting via newline folding. Normally this causes the final newline to be included in the string but the `-` tells it not to do this.)

The intricacies of YAML quoting aren't spelled out in an easily digestible way in [the YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), but the Perl docs have [a good explanation](http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/03/strings-in-yaml---to-quote-or-not-to-quote.html).

Answer (score 1):

Browserified **YAML 1.2 parser / writer for JavaScript** ([js-yaml](https://pastebin.com/PcCb27LS)) and code with additional space:

```js
function callBackFunc(require,module,exports) {
  const yaml = require('js-yaml');

  const content = {
    stages: {
      jobs: [{
          scripts: [
            '/opt/scripts/git/git-repository-information-restore.sh',
            'cp ${bamboo.gitconfig_path} ${bamboo.build.working.directory}',
            'cp ${bamboo.npmrc_path} ${bamboo.build.working.directory}',
            'cp ${bamboo.gitcredentials_path} ${bamboo.build.working.directory}',
            ' docker build --build-arg VERSION=patch --build-arg REPO=${bamboo.planRepository.repositoryUrl} --no-cache .',
            '/opt/scripts/docker/stop-docker-containers.sh'
          ]
        },
        {
          requirements: 'REMOTE_ONLY'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  var ret = yaml.safeDump(content);
  console.log(ret)
}

$.getScript( "https://pastebin.com/raw/PcCb27LS", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun - snappy JS code compression used to store exported lib + code to unpack & execute it:

```js
function callBackFunc(require, module, exports) {
    const yaml = require('js-yaml');

    const content = {
        stages: {
            jobs: [{
                scripts: [
                    '/opt/scripts/git/git-repository-information-restore.sh',
                    'cp ${bamboo.gitconfig_path} ${bamboo.build.working.directory}',
                    'cp ${bamboo.npmrc_path} ${bamboo.build.working.directory}',
                    'cp ${bamboo.gitcredentials_path} ${bamboo.build.working.directory}',
                    ' docker build --build-arg VERSION=patch --build-arg REPO=${bamboo.planRepository.repositoryUrl} --no-cache .',
                    '/opt/scripts/docker/stop-docker-containers.sh'
                ]
            },
            {
                requirements: 'REMOTE_ONLY'
            }
            ]
        }
    }
    var ret = yaml.safeDump(content);
    console.log(ret)
}

// The MIT License (MIT)
// ... as mimified browser version of https://github.com/zhipeng-jia/snappyjs/blob/master/snappy_decompressor.js (1234B below)
var WORD_MASK=[0,255,65535,16777215,4294967295];function copyBytes(r,e,s,t,o){var n;for(n=0;n<o;n++)s[t+n]=r[e+n]}function selfCopyBytes(r,e,s,t){var o;for(o=0;o<t;o++)r[e+o]=r[e-s+o]}function SnappyDecompressor(r){this.array=r,this.pos=0}SnappyDecompressor.prototype.readUncompressedLength=function(){for(var r,e,s=0,t=0;t<32&&this.pos<this.array.byteLength;){if(r=this.array[this.pos],this.pos+=1,(e=127&r)<<t>>>t!==e)return-1;if(s|=e<<t,r<128)return s;t+=7}return-1},SnappyDecompressor.prototype.uncompressToBuffer=function(r){for(var e,s,t,o,n=this.array,p=n.length,i=this.pos,a=0;i<n.length;)if(e=n[i],i+=1,0==(3&e)){if((s=1+(e>>>2))>60){if(i+3>=p)return!1;t=s-60,s=1+((s=n[i]+(n[i+1]<<8)+(n[i+2]<<16)+(n[i+3]<<24))&WORD_MASK[t]),i+=t}if(i+s>p)return!1;copyBytes(n,i,r,a,s),i+=s,a+=s}else{switch(3&e){case 1:s=4+(e>>>2&7),o=n[i]+(e>>>5<<8),i+=1;break;case 2:if(i+1>=p)return!1;s=1+(e>>>2),o=n[i]+(n[i+1]<<8),i+=2;break;case 3:if(i+3>=p)return!1;s=1+(e>>>2),o=n[i]+(n[i+1]<<8)+(n[i+2]<<16)+(n[i+3]<<24),i+=4}if(0===o||o>a)return!1;selfCopyBytes(r,a,o,s),a+=s}return!0},SnappyDecompressor.prototype.uncompressToString=function(){var r=this.readUncompressedLength(),e=new ArrayBuffer(r);return this.uncompressToBuffer(e),ab2str(e)};

// packed base64 js-yaml (26187B of mimified 41978B or original 112611B):
var pck = "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";
var compressed = atob(pck);
compressed = str2ab(compressed);
var res;
var decompressor = new SnappyDecompressor(compressed)
res = decompressor.uncompressToString();
eval(res);

function ab2str(buffer) {
    var length = buffer.byteLength;
    var result = '';

    for (var i = 3; i < length; i++) {

        result += String.fromCharCode(buffer[i]);
    }

    return result;
}

function str2ab(str) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (var i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bufView;
}
```